# Magnetic field direction

Tags: force-fields

I need to know if you can create three magnetic fields with orthogonal directions to each other, meaning one having it's direction on the x axis , one on the y axis and one on the z axis, the only direction I've found in blender field options is the z direction, can you create magnetic fields with different directions from the  z axis in blender?

Comment: Does it help if you rotate the empties themselves which have those force fields assigned ?